# How a Boolean Algebra is a $\bf F_2-$ Vector Space?

Tags: boolean-algebra

In a answer of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918195/a-problem-in-sigma-algebra?noredirect=1&lq=1) question it's said that "A ($\sigma$-)algebra is a boolean algebra. In particular, it is an $\Bbb F_2$ vector space."

> Unfortunately i have never seen this term Boolean Algebra.Could someone please explain me what is a Boolean Algebra and how is this a $\Bbb F_2$ vector space?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Boolean algebra of subsets of $X$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ that is closed under finite union, finite intersection and taking complements, and contains $\emptyset$ and $X$ itself.

(Of course, there is also an abstract definition of Boolean algebras as well.)

Any Boolean algebra becomes an $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space: the "addition" is symmetric difference $$A + B = (A \backslash B) \cup (B \backslash A),$$ and the zero element is $\emptyset.$

The answer you linked to does not seem to be valid, though: infinite-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector spaces do not need to be uncountable sets, and there do exist countably infinite Boolean algebras.

Comment: I dont think i understand it completely.What is the scalar multiplication here? and Could you give example of countably infinite Boolean Algebra?

Comment: The scalar multiplication is $0 \cdot x = 0$ and $1 \cdot x = x$. For a countably infinite Boolean algebra, you can take the finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ and their complements.