# If $\mathcal{M}$ is an infinite $\sigma$-algebra, then $|\mathcal{M}| \geq \mathfrak{c}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be an infinite $\sigma$-algebra. Show that $|\mathcal{M}| \geq \mathfrak{c}$

I was wondering if this procedure works for any representation of numbers in $[0,1)$ to show that an infinite $\sigma$-algebra has cardinality greater than or equal to $\mathfrak{c}$. I saw this done using binary representations of numbers in $[0,1)$. Would it be the same approach using ternary representations?

Let $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an infinite sequence of disjoint sets in $\mathcal{M}$. For any $x \in [0,1)$ fix a ternary representation $x=\sum\limits_{k=1}c_k3^{-k}, c_k \in \{0,1,2\}$. Define a function $\phi:[0,1) \rightarrow \mathcal{M}$ by $\phi(\sum\limits_{k=1}c_k3^{-k})=\bigcup\limits_{\substack{k \geq1\\c_k=1}}A_k$. Since $\phi$ is injective, $|\mathcal{M}| \geq \mathfrak{c}=|[0,1)|$. Would this be correct? Finally, how can one show the map $\phi$ is injective.

Also, what are more intuitive ways to do this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map is not injective. Consider $c_{1}=1$ and $c_{k}=0$ for $k>1$ as well as $b_{1}=1$ and $b_{k}=2$ for $k>1$. Then $$x=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}c_{k}3^{-k}\ne\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}b_{i}3^{-i}=y$$
but $\phi(x)=\phi(y)=A_{1}$.

The simplest in my opinion is to use binary sequences $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ instead of ternary representation since you avoid this kind of counter-example. Note also that this is somewhat different from a binary representation in that a number can have multiple binary representations ($1/2=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}1/2^{n}$) while binary sequences which differ at a particular entry can be considered different.

For completeness I'll mention the map:
$$\phi:\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}\to\mathcal{M} \quad (b_{k})\mapsto\bigcup_{k, b_{k}=1}A_{k}$$ The uncountability of $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$follows readily from a Cantor diagonal type argument.

Comment: If you use binary instead with $\phi(\sum\limits_{k=1}c_k2^{-k})=\bigcup\limits_{\substack{k \geq1\\c_k=1}}A_k$ how would you show this map is injective?

Comment: If $x\ne y$ then $c_{k}\ne b_{k}$ for some $k$ but then they cannot map to the same set as the sets $A_{j}$ are disjoint. To be precise we use here that if $c_{k}\ne b_{k}$ then either $c_{k}$ or $b_{k}$ is $1$.

Comment: Are there any easier ways to show $|\mathcal{M}| \geq \mathfrak{c}$ that you know of? I saw a proof by contradiction that assumes it has cardinality of natural numbers, which is more involved.

Comment: I can't really think of any other argument, I have only recently started studying measure theory so my arguments are limited. But, there seems to be some [other ways](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918195/a-problem-in-sigma-algebra/918204#918204) (not sure if they are easier though). Do you have a link to the contradiction argument?

Comment: Oh I guess this is slightly different, it only proves that there is no $\sigma$-algebra with cardinality the same as the rationals but here https://ericauldmathblog.wordpress.com/2014/07/03/there-are-no-countably-infinite-sigma-algebras/